# Is there an elegant way to increment the index of 'arr' without x?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to improve my Python and I'm curious if there's an elegant way to increment the index of `arr` in the loop without using integer `x` in this code:

```
def predict_one_instance(xSeriesTestVector, xTrainInstances, yTrainCategories, distanceMetric, k):

    distances = calc_distances(xSeriesTestVector, xTrainInstances,distanceMetric)
    sorted_distances = np.sort(distances)
    arr = np.zeros((k,), dtype=int)
    x = 0   
    for el in sorted_distances[:k]:
        arr[x] = yTrainCategories.iloc[np.where(distances == el)]
        x+=1
    return np.bincount(arr).argmax()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

```
for item in iterable:
    do_stuff(item)
```

can be turned to

```
for i, item in enumerate(iterable):
    do_stuff(item, i)
```

where `i` contains the index of `item` in the  `iterable`.

So, in your example:

```
for x, el in enumerate(sorted_distances[:k]):
    arr[x] = yTrainCategories.iloc[np.where(distances == el)]
```

Although you might as well use the good old `range` if your `iterable` is a `list`:

```
for x in range(k):
    arr[x] = yTrainCategories.iloc[np.where(distances == sorted_distances[x])]
```